# How can we show the inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, irrational-numbers

Let $h_1,h_2:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions.

How can we show that $h_1(x)\leq h_2(x)$ for each $x\in [0,1]$, given that $h_1(x)
\leq h_2(x)$ for each $x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ ?

Do we use the density of irrationals?

Comment: Use the density of rationals in the reals, along with continuity .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the density of the rationals.  If there's a point in $x\not\in\Bbb Q$ where $h_1(x)>h_2(x)$ then by continuity there's a whole interval where that inequality holds and therefore there's a rational where it holds, and that's your contradiction.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: There is also an other question.... Suppose that $h_1,h_2:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions. 
I want to show that there is a $\epsilon>0$ such that $|h_1(x)-h_2(x)|\geq \epsilon$ for each $x\in [0,1]$, given that $h_1(x)\neq h_2(x)$ for each $x\in [0,1]$? 
$$$$ 
I have done the following:

Comment: We know that $h_1(x)\neq h_2(x)$ for each $x\in [0,1]$, that means that $f(x):=h_1(x)-h_2(x)$ is either $>0$ or $<0$ but never $=0$. 
$$$$ 
Therefore, we have that $|f(x)|>0, \forall x\in [0,1]$. That means that there is a $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(x)|\geq \epsilon, \forall x\in [0,1]$. 
$$$$ 
Is this correct?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that's basically the same argument as the original question.  The basic reasoning is that if $f$ is continuous and $f(a)>0$ then $\exists$ $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$.  That follows basically directly from the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of continuity.

Comment: Ah ok... Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

*A simple* $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ *proof:*

By continuity of $h_1$, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that for any $x'\in (x-\delta_1,x+\delta_1)$, $\;\lvert h_1(x)-h_1(x')\rvert <\varepsilon$.

Similarly,  there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that  $\;\lvert h_2(x)-h_2(x')\rvert <\varepsilon\;$ for any $x'\in (x-\delta_1, x+\delta_2)$. Hence if $ \delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ and $ x'\in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$, we'll have both
$$\lvert h_1(x)-h_1(x')\rvert\enspace\text{and}\enspace\lvert h_2(x)-h_2(x')\rvert <\varepsilon.$$
Now suppose $h_1(x)>h_2(x)$ for some real number $x$. Choose $\;\varepsilon<\dfrac{h_1(x)-h_2(x)}2\;$ and a *rational* $x'$. Then we'll get
$$h_2(x')<h_2(x)+\delta<h_1(x)-\delta<h_1(x')$$
which contradicts the hypothesis on the  values of $h_1$ and $h_2$ for the rational values of $x'$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!! :-)